# How to open a secret tab in Chrome?

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

Using `webbrowser` module and `webbrowser.open` method, we can open URL in new tab.
However, is there any way we can open a secret tab in Google by using Python?

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open_new("http://google.com")
```

Comment: What's a "secret tab"? Do you mean private/incognito mode?

Comment: A [secret tab](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+a+chrome+secret+tab&rlz=1C1OKWM_enUS773US773&oq=what+is+a+chrome+secret+tab&aqs=chrome..69i57.4722j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is an incognito tab.

Comment: @LakshyaRaj except that it's not called a Secret Tab

Comment: @SiHa : True but I guess for this type of thing, we have to understand :) 

Comment: Are you sure that "webbrowser.open_new()" will open Chrome? What happens if my default browser is Firefox? Or a browser that does not allow "incognito" mode?

Answer (score 2):

You'd be better off using `os.system()` to launch chrome with incognito argument.

Example: `os.system("C:\path\to\chrome\executable.exe -ArgumentList @( '-incognito','https://www.google.com'")`

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use the method you are using to open a 'secret tab'.  Try this:

```py
webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s --incognito")
.open("<URL YOU WANT TO OPEN>")
```

The special part is `--incognito`.  It signifies incognito mode (to open a secret/incognito tab). `%s` is used to signify the URL to open (specified by the `.open` function).  A side note: you can NOT replace `%s` with your URL, or else it raises `webbrowser.Error`.